# how to use server side button click event in mvc4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have to make a textbox somewhere in the page and a button using **ASPX View Engine**.That page already contains partial views. User will enter his data (code) on textbox and at button click, server code will manipulate that data and show an alert or message that data is processed. How to do that in mvc4?

I have found that we can write server script in page like

```
<script runat="server">

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
       ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, [GetType](), "showalert", "alert('Message Sent');", True)
    End Sub
    Private Sub DataProcess(ByVal Data As String)
        'Code to check data
    End Sub
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate `Ajax Form` ccontaining only this button and the textbox. So you will call an `Action` in a certain `controller` then this `Action` will return a string or a Json. And via an UpdateTargetId property you can display a dialog box. Giving you the code is difficult because I don't know the structure of your code. You can aslo write the `Ajax` call using Jquery.

This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381533%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) can help you

Comment: can you give me simple code for calling server code on button click event?

Comment: click on `link`. And choose `vb` code section. You will have your answer